# How to insert a entry in last position of a TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap

I have a list of entries to select from a drodown, like A, B, C, D, E etc.
So I have used a tree map to display the same i sorted order. But in the last entry I want a 'Add New Record' option value which will be used to create a new option. If User selects 'Add New Record' then a new text box will appear and new entry can be made.

Now the problem is I want the option 'Add New Record' as last option in the dropdown. But as the treemap is sorted the value in the dropdown is getting displayed as A,Add New Record, B, C, D, E etc.
How can I Put the 'Add New Record' at the last option value in Java.

Please suggest.

Comment: (I doubt you're tackling this problem best by delegating the sorting to a TreeMap, but anyway...) You simply need to create a custom comparator that sorts `"Add New Record"` after anything else.

Comment: which technology are you using for UI?

Comment: Do you really need this static entry "Add New Record" in your record set. You may add this text as constant text value to dropdown at end, this way you will save any extra operation which will required custom comparator

Comment: I would not store it in the map at all. Just iterate over the map to display the standard options, and then display the 'add new record' option. Or use a List instead of a Map.

Comment: I am using JSP as UI

Comment: @AsifBilla There is no necessity to add that item in treemap right ? Just to show option in UI

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `TreeMap`.

Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which iterates over its entries in insertion order; simply insert the entries in the order you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Most easy solution is  do not add `"Add a new record"` into the TreeMap.

Add that value to your widget after the `Treemap` items added to the widget, what so ever technology you are using in UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in java, (as you have put the `java` tag). You can you use the `ArrayList`. It maintain the insertion order of the elements.

```java
public class ListExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add("one");
    myList.add("two");
    myList.add("three");
    myList.add("four");
    myList.add("five");

    for (String string : myList) {
      System.out.println(string);
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
one
two
three
four
five
```